# String comparison (using "or" in a "do while loop") java

Tags: java

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this code loops indefinitely when "turnOrder" is set to "first." It seems to be something about the "or" operator in the "do while loop." But I have no idea how to properly format it.

```
String turnOrder;
    do {
        Scanner to = new Scanner(System.in);
        turnOrder = to.nextLine();
        if ((!"first".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder)) || (!"second".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder))) {
            System.out.println("Type your answer as 'first' or 'second.' Without the punctuation.");
        } else {}
    } while ((!"first".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder)) || (!"second".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder)));
```

Comment: Well...it doesn't `equalsIgnoreCase` `"second"`.

Comment: I thought with and "or" operator one of the statments could be false, and the expression as a whole would be true

Comment: You should always reduce your logic operations to their simplest form.

Comment: If one of the operands is `true`, then the entire expression is `true`. What part of your `if` statement will execute if the expression is `true`?

Comment: That's what happens. turnOrder is "first", so `"second".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder)` is false, so `!"second".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder)` is true. So the whole `or` expression is true, and the loop keeps looping.

Comment: Oh. That makes sense so the "or" operator is going to be unhelpful in all cases right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It loops cause when you type "first", it returns false in
!"first".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder), BUT
it return true in 
!"second".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder))

false OR true = true, so it will keep looping

Comment: Thanks alot! I can see that the "or" operator, unfortunately, is not going to be helpful here. Do you have any compact solutions I may have overlooked?

Comment: what do you want the program to do?

Comment: The code should loop until "turnOrder" is either "first" or "second" and keep looping if it is anything else. using && instead of  || seems to have fixed the problem. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

`while ((!"first".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder)) || (!"second".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder)))`

This statement will always be true until you come up with a `turnOrder` value that equalsIgnoreCase-s to "first" and "second" simultaneously. Good luck with that! Perhaps you meant...

```
while (
    !(
      "first".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder) ||
      "second".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder)
     )
)
```

Comment: Yes that would be an interesting statement indeed. However even with your cleaner approach it keeps looping.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you are trying to do now. You are trying to loop until you get "first" or "second", not until you get something different. Oops! I'll adjust my answer to fit your actual intent.

Answer (score 0):

You should always reduce your logic operations to their simplest form.

"((!"first".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder)) || (!"second".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder)))"

can be simplified using De Morgan's Laws to

!("first".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder) && "second".equalsIgnoreCase(turnOrder))

Of course turnOrder cannot be "first" and "second" simultaneously.  It will always evaluate to true, thus your while loop will loop indefinitely.

Comment: Right, the "or" operator isn't going to work here. Thank you.